# SQLAlchemy sending a request for each entity in list

Tags: performance, orm, sqlalchemy

I turned on 'echo' on Engine and I see DB queries sent once when I call `query.all()` and then a query sent for each Report once `report.as_dict()` accesses a field.

```
query = db_session.query(Report)
query = query.filter(or_(Report.network_id == network_id, Report.network_id == None))
reports = query.all()
db_session.commit()
resp = [report.as_dict() for report in reports]
```

The query sent on `query.all()` -

```
2017-09-19 16:02:28,504 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT report.id AS report_id, report.network_id AS report_network_id, report.account_id AS report_account_id, report.name AS report_name, report.notes AS report_notes, report.structure AS report_structure, report.type AS report_type, report.version AS report_version 
FROM report WHERE report.network_id = %(network_id_1)s OR report.network_id IS NULL ORDER BY report.id
2017-09-19 16:02:28,504 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {'network_id_1': '5850'}
```

And for each report accessed on `report.as_dict()` (param_1 = report id) -

```
2017-09-19 16:04:15,100 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT report.id AS report_id, report.network_id AS report_network_id, report.account_id AS report_account_id, report.name AS report_name, report.notes AS report_notes, report.structure AS report_structure, report.type AS report_type, report.version AS report_version 
FROM report WHERE report.id = %(param_1)s
2017-09-19 16:04:15,100 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {'param_1': 1}
```

It looks like the whole list of reports is retrieved on the initial query but I still see a query sent for each of them, how can I change this behavior?
My environment: windows 10, Python 3.5.0, sqlalchemy 1.2.0b2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you have `expire_on_commit` set to `True`, so as soon as you do `session.commit()` SQLAlchemy throws away all the data you've just queried. You need to turn it off on the session.

```
db_session = Session(expire_on_commit=False)
```

Be mindful and check that this does not violate any assumptions you've made due to this.